# Unable to create Android Client ID in App Engine dev console

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to create a new Android Client ID for a Google App Engine project python backend. I thought I was experiencing a bug with app engine's new dev console, but the error occurs even with the old console interface.

Steps: In my app engine project, I click "Credentials" under the "APIs & Auth" heading.

1. Click "Create new Client ID"
2. Selected: Installed application, Android.
3. Put in my Android application package name: ca.ajwest.pythonapi
4. Paste the SHA1 key created by the keytool (I'm using a Release keystore).
5. Enable deep linking (though when set to disabled the problem still occurs)
6. Click "Create Client ID"

Results: When the lightbox fades, there is a new Android client ID with the SHA1 and package name I provided. However, when navigating away from the page or refreshing the credentials page, **the SHA1 is no longer listed on the entry, and Deep Linking is set to disabled (regardless of whether or not I had enabled it).**

What's going on with App Engine? Am I missing something here? I've generated these keys before and had no problem.

Edit: I have now tried creating an entirely new Google Account, on a different computer and browser in a different part of town, with a new Android keystone generated by Android Studio. I created a whole new App Engine project and used a new Android package name. Yet again, as soon as I refresh the page, the SHA1 key has been removed and my client id does not work.

I don't know what else to try. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for now. Create the Client API key normally, then edit the settings right away, and toggle "Deep Linking". Save and the console displays "updating" for a moment, then the SHA1 key persists on refresh. Strange bug.

Comment: Do you have any adblockers? Sounds like the JS is getting blocked.